# Partial Derivative of Joint Distribution of Circular Uniform RVs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, self-learning

From the book *An Introduction to Copulas* ([Nelson, 2006](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=B3ONT5rBv0wC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)) page 55, the distribution function of RVs $X = \cos(\Theta)$ and $Y = \sin(\Theta)$ denoted by $H(x,y)$, where $\Theta$ is a uniform random variable on the interval $[0, 2\pi)$, is

\begin{align}
H(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
 \frac{3}{4}-\frac{\cos ^{-1}(x)+\cos ^{-1}(y)}{2 \pi }, & x^2+y^2\leq 1 \\
 1-\frac{\cos ^{-1}(x)+\cos ^{-1}(y)}{\pi }, & x^2+y^2>1\land x\geq 0\land y\geq 0 \\
 1-\frac{\cos ^{-1}(x)}{\pi }, & x^2+y^2>1\land x<0\land y\geq 0 \\
 1-\frac{\cos ^{-1}(y)}{\pi }, & x^2+y^2>1\land x\geq 0\land y<0 \\
0, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases} 
\end{align}

[Following is plot of $H(x,y)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VWmj.png)

We know that the pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is $h(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}, \text{for}~ x^2 + y^2 =1.$

How can we get the $h(x,y)$ as $\frac{\partial^2H(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}$? I only get $0$ for each conditional. It seems I miss something.

Comment: Why do you think $H$ is twice differentiable?

Comment: @Did, it is twice differentiable on the conditional, isn't it? However, it isn't twice differentiable on $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, is it? In that case, can you give me any hint how I can get the pdf from the cdf? Or, I can't?

Comment: The vector $(X,Y)$ has no PDF since $P((X,Y)\in C)=1$ with $C$ of Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: @Did Does it mean that my statement about the pdf is equal to $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ wrong?

Comment: If something does not exist, can it be equal to, say, $1/(2\pi)$?